# What programming language is used in the picture?

Tags: pseudocode

What programming language is used in the picture?

I do not kown the following language that maybe R or pseudo-code.

```
 '''
1: procedure Discriminator Gd(0)
2:   δ ← 0.01
3:   ξ D,0 ← ξ D
4:   d 0 ← L()
5:   b D ← [0,0]
6:   for i ← 1 to 2 do
7:     c ← c + 1
8:     ξ D [i] ← ξ D [i] + δ
9:     d ← L()
10:    b D [i] ← (d − d 0 )/δ
11:    ξ D ← ξ D,0
12:  end for
13:  b D ← b D /norm(b D )
14:  return b D
15: end procedure
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a psuedo-code block rather than an example block of a specific language, just as you expected.

The sample code can be found [here](https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/advances/suppl/2019/01/18/5.1.eaav2761.DC1/aav2761_SM.pdf) on page 5 (Algorithm 4) in a paper containing supplementary materials regarding Quantum Generative Adversarial Learning. The additional variable names are meant to be subscripts. They use this form of psuedo-code throughout the paper, as mentioned beneath Algorithm 1 on page 2.